# Orientation issue in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, orientation

I am using React native orientation module. I need a Landscape view for only onescreen. So in componentDidMount() wrote loackToLandscape() and when going back I wrote lockToProtrait().

My code is as follows:

```
componentWillMount(){

  if(this.props.sportName == 'Pro Football'){
    Orientation.lockToLandscape();

    this.setState({
      HEIGHT:375,
      WIDTH:667


    })
  }
  else{
   Orientation.lockToPortrait();
  }

}
onBack(){
  Orientation.lockToPortrait();
       this.setState({
        open:false
      })
  }
```

When **autorotation** is false it working fine. But when **autorotation** is on when I change my device to portrait then the view is also changing to portrait. But I want it to be locked to landscape.

Answer (score 2):

just You have to try this:

Add both two lines in AppDelegate.m

```
#import "../../node_modules/react-native-orientation/iOS/RCTOrientation/Orientation.h"

 - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    return [Orientation getOrientation];
  }
```

you will get the result, before you will follow the  this link:

first you are follow the link how to lock to landscape

https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation